# amazon-s3-php-class - how to change permission

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm using the `amazon-s3-php-class` to help me upload files to Amazon's S3.   After I upload the file,  i noticed that Everyone can download it if they type the url `https://url.com/mybucket/filename.file`.

I can manually restrict access by using the AWS console to turn off Open/Download to the user Everyone.

How do I do this with programatically with `amazon-s3-php-class`?  The following code did not do anything:

```
$s3 = new S3($AZ_KEY_ID, $AZ_KEY_SECRET);
$acp = array("acl"=>array());

$acp["acl"][] = array(
"type" => "Everyone", "uri" => "https://url.com/mybucket/filename.file", "permission" => ""
);

$s3->setAccessControlPolicy("mybucket", "https://url.com/mybucket/filename.file", $acp);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$s3 = new S3($AZ_KEY_ID, $AZ_KEY_SECRET);
$acp = $s3->getAccessControlPolicy('mybucket', 'filename.file');
foreach($acp['acl'] as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($val['uri']) && 
        $val['uri'] == 'http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers')
        unset($acp['acl'][$key]);        
}
$s3->setAccessControlPolicy('mybucket', 'filename.file', $acp)
```

In function `getAccessControlPolicy` and `setAccessControlPolicy`, `uri` should be the path related to bucket.

AllUsers equals Everyone at AWS console.

Or you can set private acl to an object, when inserting it to S3.

`$s3->putObjectFile($uploadFile, 'mybucket', 'filename.file', S3::ACL_PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 8):

With the new AWS SDK V3 changing ACL permissions is really easy:

```
 $s3->putObjectAcl([
                        'Bucket' => 'myBucketName',
                        'Key' => 'myFileName',
                        'ACL' => 'private'
                    ]);
```

ACL can be one of these value  'ACL' => 'private|public-read|public-read-write|authenticated-read|aws-exec-read|bucket-owner-read|bucket-owner-full-control',

Comment: Ok but how to do with all keys when there's thousands of it?